# How to find Schema of a Collection in MongoDB using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, pymongo

How can I get the data types of all the keys in the MongoDB collection using Pymongo??

Example:

[image: -]

Comment: Have you created a schema using schema validation?

Comment: I have a Mongo database that I did not create nor our architect, is there a good way to
introspect the DB or print out what the structure is to start to get a handle on what types of data are being stored, how the data types are nested?